# BASH: Why `printf` returns 1?

Tags: bash, printf, return-value

I have a problem that gaslights me.

Here comes my bash script "foo" reduced to the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

function Args()
{
    [[ "$1" == "-n" ]] && [[ -d "$2" ]] && printf "%s\n" "new ${3}"
    [[ "$1" == "-p" ]] && [[ -d "$2" ]] && printf "%s\n" "page ${3}"
}

[[ $# -eq 3 ]] && Args "$@"
echo $?
```

Now when I execute this code, the following happens:

```
$ ./foo -n / bar
new bar
1
```

This, however, works:

```
$ ./foo -p / bar
page bar
0
```

Please, can anybody explain?

Sorry if this is a known "thing" and my googleing skills must be improved...

Comment: AHHH, me stupid noob! I know the problem.. thanks anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is returning `1` in first case only because 2nd condition:

```
[[ "$1" == "-p" ]] && [[ -d "$2" ]] && printf "%s\n" "page ${3}"
```

won't match/apply when you call your script as:

```
./foo -n / bar
```

And due to non-matching of 2nd set of conditions it will return 1 to you since `$?` represents most recent command's exit status which is actually exit status of 2nd set of conditions.

When you call your script as:

```
./foo -p / bar
```

It returns status `0` to you since 2nd line gets executed and that is also the most recently executed one.